# Google Dart Error

Tags: dart

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:io';
void main() {
  int guess;
  Random rand = new Random(); //create a random number generator
  int answer = rand.nextInt(100); //gets a random integer from 0 to 99 do {
  print("Enter your guess:");
  String temp = stdin.readLineSync(); //read in from the keyboard guess = int.parse(temp); //convert String to integer
  if (guess < answer) {
    print("Too low!");
  } else if (guess > answer) {
    print("Too high!");
  }
} 
while (guess != answer);
  print("You got it!");
}
```

What is wrong?? I deleted the } in

```dart
} while (guess != answer);
print("You got it!");
```

and now in the console it says
Enter your guess:
32
Breaking on exception: object of type NoSuchMethodError

Comment: can you please add the stack trace or at least the line where the exception was thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `guess` variable is always null as it's never assigned (it's commented out), try changing your code to:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
   int guess;
   Random rand = new Random(); //create a random number generator
   int answer = rand.nextInt(100); //gets a random integer from 0 to 99 
   do {
      print("Enter your guess:");
      String temp = stdin.readLineSync(); //read in from the keyboard 
      guess = int.parse(temp); //convert String to integer <-- the assignment is what's missing here 

      if (guess < answer) {
          print("Too low!");
      } else if (guess > answer) {
          print("Too high!");
      }
   } while (guess != answer);
   print("You got it!");
}
```

There is a related issue with the `readLineSync` [here](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18902) which you might want to have a look.

Comment: Thank you sir! I am a idiot :D But im learning :) have a great day your help is well and always appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because `guess` is `null` and `null` has no `>`/`<` operator.
`guess` is `null` because you never assign a value.

If `guess` and `answer` are not equal this makes a perfect endless loop:

```dart
while (guess != answer);
  print("You got it!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow I failed. Man im tired seems I was typing way to sloppy/fast and left some of my code in the comments :( found it right after seeing this post sigh.. this is the correct working code

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:io';
void main() {
  int guess;
  Random rand = new Random(); //create a random number generator
  int answer = rand.nextInt(100); //gets a random integer from 0 to 99 
do {
  print("Enter your guess:");
  String temp = stdin.readLineSync(); //read in from the keyboard 
guess = int.parse(temp); //convert String to integer
  if (guess < answer) {
    print("Too low!");
  } else if (guess > answer) {
    print("Too high!");
  }
} 
while (guess != answer);
  print("You got it!");
}
```

Thats enough learning of Dart for today. Thanks everyone for the quick replies seems the Dart community is active!

im off to bed! have a great day